# How to solve malformed URI while using elasticdump?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastcsearch 7.9 and elasticdump 6.7

I am trying to get a dump (.json) file from elastcsearch with all the documents of a index.

I am getting

```
Thu, 27 May 2021 06:26:35 GMT | starting dump
Thu, 27 May 2021 06:26:35 GMT | Error Emitted => URI malformed
Thu, 27 May 2021 06:26:35 GMT | Error Emitted => URI malformed
Thu, 27 May 2021 06:26:35 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Thu, 27 May 2021 06:26:35 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => URIError: URI malformed
```

My command

```
elasticdump \
  --input=https://username:password@elasticsearchURL:9200/index \
  --output=/home/ubuntu/dump.json \
  --type=data
```

Here the problem is password have many special characters.
I cant change the password.

I tried

1. quotes for password.
2. Escape special character.
3. Encoding the url

for all cases I am getting same error

Please help me to send password with special characters(@ & % ^ * : ) , $)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made mistake that I have encoded the complete URL.Don't encode the complete URL.

Encode the password while adding password into url.

for example

Password - a@b)c#d%e*f.^gh

Encoded password - a%40b%29c%23d%25e*f.%5Egh

**My script will be:**

```
elasticdump \
  --input=https://username:a%40b%29c%23d%25e*f.%5Egh@elasticsearchURL:9200/index \
  --output=/home/ubuntu/dump.json \
  --type=data
```

Please refer [ASCII Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) for encoding the password

Answer (score 0):

actually, ı  tried  elastisdump but properly not  working,you should use  elastic `snapshot`,maybe working in less data but if data  is  big  elasticdump wont  work

loook at  the `elastic snapshot`

[snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html)

for example using snapshot

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_fs_backup?pretty
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/home/zeus/Desktop/denesnapshot", 
    "compress": true
  }
}
#chmod 777 /home/zeus/Desktop/denesnapshot

#create repo 
PUT /_snapshot/my_fs_backup/deneme

#get all repo
GET /_snapshot/my_fs_backup/_all



#if you want delete repo

DELETE /_snapshot/my_fs_backup/deneme



#restore
POST /_snapshot/my_fs_backup/deneme/_restore
```

extra you should add

```
path.repo: /home/zeus/Desktop/denesnapshot
```

to elasticsearch.yml file

> **I imported 1.5 million data and that was 300GB**

Comment: I need to save it as a file on my local system. for that from where I have to send the above snapshot requests?

Comment: of course with Kibana ,if you using elasticsearch  you should use the kibana for elastic management ...

Comment: when you create any shopshot ,that  snapshot  all of elastic index data write writes to the specified folder

Comment: Yes. I am using kibana too. My doubt is where the file is stored when I request from kibana?

Comment: in my example store will at  /home/zeus/Desktop/denesnapshot

Comment: I think you are using elasticsearch and kibana installed in your local system. I am using elastcsearch from aws. So I am having doubt that where the file is stored. Do I need to configure the path some where?

Comment: ı don't used  AWS services