I want to load a elastic index data into json using elastic dump
I'm planning to load elastic index data into json file using elastic dump my password is having double quotes which is stared but not ended i have tried to escape it "\ way but it did not work.
I have installed the elasticdump module globally :
"npm install elasticdump -g "
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 
elasticdump \
--input=https://elastic:4erw"x25{67@localhost:9200/employee \
--output=./data/sample_file.json \
--type=data

Error:
bash: @localhost:9200/employee: No such file or directory
Fri, 05 Apr 2024 09:25:07 GMT | Error Emitted => {"errors":["`output` is a required input"]}



which elasticdump

~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/elasticdump

i have tried by adding this path still not working 




Your elastic password 4erw"x25{67 has special characters. This can be the issue. Check the following link, encode the password and try again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716896/how-to-solve-malformed-uri-while-using-elasticdump

I have one more question is there any way to load the data from elastic index to CSV file using elastic dump I have tried this way but getting issues :
./bin/elasticdump 
--input=https://elastic:password@localhost:9200/sample 
--output ""csv:///sample.csv""
--type=data
--csvSkipRows 1
--csvDelimiter ";"
Can you please suggest any solution i didn't find any solution for it

Happy to hear it worked! Please open another question for that and let me try to answer

please re-edit the question to as is at the beginning, and accept the answer if it works for you. Otherwise, your question won't help others...

Your elastic password 4erw"x25{67 has special characters. This is causing issue during the curl request. Encode the password and try again.
You can use online ASCII encoders website for transform.
You can refer and generate an encoded password in the following link.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP
Check the following link for similar case.
How to solve malformed URI while using elasticdump?
